# What is the difference between $O(N/ \log_2(N))$ and $N-o(N)$?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity, cryptography

On the second page of [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vinodv/AGV-proc.pdf) under the introduction section they say

"We first show that for the set of parameters considered by [16], the function family has [$O(N/ \log_2(N))$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x/log2%28x%29) simultaneously hardcore bits.  Next we introduce a new parameter regime for which we prove that the function family is still trapdoor one-way and has up to $N - o(N)$ simultaneously hardcore bits."

What are the authors trying to say about their new parameter regime? That's it's better or worse? I tried to graph $O(N/ \log_2(N))$ to see how it looks and I can see that the growth rate is slower than a linear function like O(N).

So $N-o(N)$ = something that is linear - something that grows slower than linear = something else that grows slower than linear.  So the new parameter regime is better than $O(N/ \log_2(N))$ ?

I'm not sure I am following what they are trying to say.

Comment: Why do you use the tag complex-analysis ?

Comment: sorry - I misread it to be complexity analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every sequence in $N-o(N)$ is in $O(N)$ but not in $O(N/\log N)$.

Note that "something that is linear" minus "something that grows slower than linear" is "something else that grows" LINEAR, not "slower than linear". So the new parameter regime corresponds to sequences growing *faster* than those in $O(N/\log N)$.

Comment: Thanks Did - So if the new parameter regime is worse then why do the authors write the paper? Whats the point?

Comment: The new parameter regime is better, not worse. It is more resistant to a class of attacks defined in the paper because the attack has to produce more bits of the key to break the cryptosystem.

Comment: @zyx - So if the the new parameter regime is better, then how come Did said N-o(N) is worse than O(N/logN)?

Comment: Replaced "worse" by the nonambiguous "growing faster".

Comment: @Did - Yes so growing faster generally does mean worse.  So then why would the authors attempt to write the paper if their new parameter regime grows faster than whats already out there? It's like somebody writes a paper on a sorting algorithm that is O(n^8).

Comment: Better/worse is set by the context of the paper, and there more is better.  N - o(N) means the effective key size with and without the side attack is about the same.  N/log(N) is a significantly smaller effective key size.  This is what the 'hardcore bits' is intended to measure.

Comment: The authors say they "introduce a new parameter regime". This might mean the $O(N/\log N)$ previous result does not apply to this regime?

Comment: In the new parameter regime, the scheme is more secure against the side attacks.  That is the point of the paper.

Comment: Ok.  I think I'm starting to understand.  Since we have concluded O(N/logN) grows slower than N-o(N), this shows that the new parameter regime allows for *more* simultaneously hardcore bits, which is actually a good thing.  Now this makes sense.  Thanks guys!

Comment: You are welcome. Now the real stuff would be to evaluate the constants hidden in $O(\ )$ and $o(\ )$... for example $100000N/\log N$ is actually larger than $N-100000N/\log N$ for awfully large values of $N$ although it is $O(N/\log N)$ while $N-100000N/\log N$ is $N-o(N)$.

Comment: @Did - Yes I graphed both functions here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100000N%2FlogN%2C+N%E2%88%92100000N%2FlogN

Comment: Yes, and yet $N-100000N/\log N$ overcomes $100000N/\log N$ at $N\approx\exp(200000)$ which is around `10^86859`...

Comment: @Did - So are you suggesting this paper has a limitation of values of N that are awfully large?

Comment: Not really. Just mentioning the well known argument that *for practical purposes* (that is, for some fixed $k$, even "large"), a statement such as $x_n=o(y_n)$ is not sufficient by itself to compare $x_k$ and $y_k$ since its content is only *asymptotic* (that is, when $n\to\infty$).

Comment: The N - o(N) seems to be explicit in theorem 3.  I would expect that an explicit small crossover point where it beats the O(N/log(N)) can be determined from the paper, or under some reasonable assumptions.  This does not seem like a case where the hypothetical general problem of O constants materializes.  At least, one would have to point to specific spots in the paper to make the case that it does.